# How to deal with Future[Option[value]] scala

Tags: scala, promise, playframework

Below is this code snippet working well but with Await.result

```
def validate(loginRequest: LoginRequest): Option[AuthResponse] = {

   val response:Option[User] =  Await.result(userDao.getUserByUsernameAndPassword(loginRequest.username,Utilities.encrypt(loginRequest.password)),Duration.Inf )

   response match {
     case Some(value) =>populateResponse(value)
     case None =>  None
   }

}
```

I want to use Futures instead of await but then return the response. below is a non blocking snippet

```
 val response:Future[Option[User]]=  userDao.getUserByUsernameAndPassword(loginRequest.username,Utilities.encrypt(loginRequest.password))
```

How would u get a similar response without blocking

```
response match {
       case Some(value) =>populateResponse(value)
       case None =>  None
     }
```

Comment: `futureOption.map(option => option.map(values => populateResponse(value)))` - As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) is your friend.

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call `map` on the `Future` to change the result, and inside that call `map` on the `Option` to change the contents of the option:

```
response.map(_.map(populateResponse))
```

If the `Option` is `None` then the second `map` will do nothing, and if the `Future` had failed then the first `map` will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

so based on your great answers I came up with a solution. because it was an Option response.

```
response.map{
       res => res match {
         case Some(value) =>populateResponse(value)
         case None =>  None
     }
```

Comment: As I explained in my answer, the whole `match` expression can be replaced with `_.map(populateResponse)`. The whole solution is `response.map(_.map(populateResponse))`

Comment: You can also just do it as follows: `response.map { case Some(value) => populatedResponse(value) case None => None }` - the `res => res match` can be eliminated